# Idris type deriving for an arithmetic operation

Tags: polymorphism, type-inference, idris

In the following code

```
Idris> :t \x => x + x
\x => x + x : Integer -> Integer
```

Idris derives an Integer type for an x variable where I think it should derive an interface limitation like in Haskell:

```
Haskell> :t (\x y -> x + y)
(\x y -> x + y) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Then it does not even behave like an Integer, accepting a Double type:

```
Idris> (\x => x + x) 2.0 
4.0 : Double
```

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: Type inference of `Idris` is not so mature as in Haskell. With dependent types your type inference can't be so good. Probably something similar to monomorphism restriction happens here. To find better explanation of this behavior you should probably open bug in `idris-dev` repository: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues

Comment: @Shersh dependent types do not entail any limitation on type inference for non-dependent programs. Also, this case concerns generalization rather than inference, and Idris does not have generalization by design, not because of any fundamental reason.

Comment: @András Kovács could you direct me to some content on this "Idris does not have generalization by design" topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general it can be said that inspecting type inference in the REPL of idris is a bad idea. REPL code and code which exists in Idris files behaves differently.

Your desired function would be written as:

```
addy: Num a => a -> a -> a
addy x y = x + y
```

and would have a type similiar to the one you expect from Haskell. Type inference in Idris is in general very weak (because it cannot be decided for dependently typed type systems).